# Design of an antenna on a PCB card emitting between 1000 and 5000 Hz

Tags: antenna, frequency, electromagnetic, pcb-antenna

I would like to create an antena on my PCB thanks to copper track. My antenna has to be a square like a coiled coil in order to emitt a magnetic field.

Is it possible to create an antenna like that with a resonant frequency around 3000 Hz, and if yes, how can I know the length and the number of coil I need to realize my antenna. I'm looking for formula but none I already found is working for such a low frequency.

Thank you for your answers, I hope my question is clear.

[edit] so information in comments doesn't get lost

We want to develop a magnetic loop. Thanks to this, deaf person will have the possibility to hear a voice. For now, we are still in a development process. The power level of my signal will be 12V and the distance has to be around 1 meters. So that's why we don't need a lot of power, but just enough in order to work properly
[/edit]

Comment: A coil doesn't have a resonant frequency other than the parasitic self-resonant frequency in the high hundreds of kHz to way beyond. You make it resonate with a tuning capacitor. So, if you use a tuning capacitor, the answer is yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Andyaka Hello, thank you, I was using a capacitor of 150 pF in order to have a resonant frequency. So if I understood well your answer, switching the value of the capacitor will change the value of the resonant frequency ?

Comment: Put these details in the question; not in comments. What frequency did it resonate at with 150 pF? Did you calculate the inductance required for the coil to resonate at 3 kHz? You will need probably tens of microfarads to get any reasonably sized coil resonant at 3 kHz.

Comment: The standard L and C formulae work just fine at low frequencies as well as high frequencies. Perhaps you're having trouble getting your head around how low the inductance is for a PCB surface coil, so what an enormous capacitance you need to resonate at kHz. 150 pF sounds waaaay too small for any practical PCB coil.

Comment: @Andyaka Indeed, the value i was using was giving me a really high inductance (around 18H, seems not possible). With 10 microfarad I have around 0.3mH. 

If I follow what you said, I have to add this capacitor at end of line of my coil ?
I'm sorry that's the first time I'm working at such low frequency so I feel a bit lost

Comment: @Bouboubi What are you trying to accomplish with this? Those frequencies are in the audio range. 1/4 wavelength at 3 khz is around 15 miles (24 km), the length of 'antenna' you can get on a circuit board will be very inefficient. What distance are you hoping to get? What power level will your signal source be?

Comment: @GodJihyo We want to develop a magnetic loop. Thanks to this, deaf person will have the possibility to hear a voice. For now, we are still in a development process.
The power level of my signal will be 12V and the distance has to be around 1 meters. So that's why we don't need a lot of power, but just enough in order to work properly

Comment: If you want to transmit audio frequencies, for hearing, you do not want resonance. You just have to use current drive, and enough of it. What is typically done is to loop a length of 3-core mains cable around the entire area where the deaf person is expected to stand, put the three turns in series, and use an audio amplifier to drive a 4 ohm resistor in series with those turns to get a crude current drive, easy, cheap and effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q) How many turns and what length of wire?

A) As many as possible, as much as possible. The inductance of your coil will probably be the limiting factor, for reasonable sizes of PCB.

Let's assume a 10 turn square coil, with a side of 100 mm (you have to start somewhere, to get a feel for what's involved). That will have an inductance of the order of 50 uH, according to [this](https://www.qsl.net/in3otd/ind1calc.html) online calculator.

That needs a 56 uF capacitor connected in parallel with it, to resonate at 3 kHz, if you are going to shunt feed it from a high impedance driver. If you are going to drive it from a very low impedance, then you would put the capacitor in series.

A larger or smaller coil, with more or fewer turns, will need a correspondingly different value of capacitor.

Using a capacitor to resonate it means that it will work well only over a small range of frequencies. If you want to transmit intelligible telephony-grade audio, so 300 Hz to 3 kHz, you cannot use resonance. Just have a coil, and current drive it with your audio waveform.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now I understand that the coil doesn't impact anything if my capacitor is coherent at the end.

Comment: @Bouboubi There is a second consideration, and that's the Q of the coil. How sharp a resonance do you need, or what magnification factor do you need? The LC tank impedance is sqrt(L/C) ohms. Compare that to your (mostly resistive) losses. The ratio will give you the Q. If you really want broadband operation between 1 kHz and 5 kHz, the Q will need to be so low that it's not worth bothering with resonance.

Comment: Shunt feeding it from high impedance probably isn't going to do much, the impedance of something like this will be maybe a couple of ohms.

Comment: @GodJihyo It's a resonant circuit, the C cancels out the L to the extent that the Q allows. You have two options with an LC tank, current-feed a parallel (high impedance) tank, or voltage-feed a series (low impedance) tank. With the figures I gave, 50 uH, 56 uF, that's 1 ohm. 'High Impedance' and 'Low Impedance' drive in this context mean 'with respect to the LC impedance'. It's also common to inductively feed a parallel LC from a voltage source, you just need to do the Thevenin on the two Ls to get your new resonant frequency.

Comment: @Neil_UK Okay, so what, a factor of 10 then?

Comment: @GodJihyo a ratio of 10 limits you to a Q of 10. However, the whole resonance thing is moot anyway, as the OP needs a flat response.